# Finding same activity and sum volume

Tags: excel, vba

I would need a help in Excel VBA. I need from I3 to I20 check all activities, find same activities in column A, then read number in column C of that activity and sum it that there is a formula(sum or just + between cells ) and paste it in column M.

In picture it is "aktivnost 1" in I3, so it will in M2 sum C2, C3 C4, C5, C7...ect.
Then it wil go to next row and do the same up to row I20.

[image: Picture]

Thank you

Comment: `SUMIFS` in the formula?

Comment: Yes, same as it is sumifs, but it is not for me, that is why i need VBA to put button

Comment: also on sumifs, I always get #VALUE error so this code would help me a lot.

Comment: does that mean it can only be coded?  the error can be handled at formula level too?

Comment: I think it is because of length, so it must be shorten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the formula solution:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$10,I2,$B$2:$B$10)
```

[image]

Here is VBA Solution:

```
    Sub SUMIF()

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("M2").Value = Application.SUMIF(.Range("A2:A10"), _
                              "*" & .Range("I2").Value & "*", _
                            .Range("B2:B10"))
    End With

End Sub
```